# Rails app on iOS: link_to destroy_path method: delete, Prompts the User to Download

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails

Issue: On an iOS Device, when the User selects 'X' to dismiss a notification, they are prompted by iOS to download a file.

- Rails 6.0.0
- Ruby 3.0.0

ERB Link from user's nation index.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to destroy_nation_notifications_path(notification), method: :delete do %>
    <span class="dismiss-btn gray float-right">ⓧ</span>
<% end %>
```

Routes:

```
  resource :nation_notifications do
    delete :destroy, path: ':id', as: 'destroy'
  end
```

Controller:

```
  def destroy
    @notification = NationNotification.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @notification.delete
  end
```

Works on Web. On iOS devices, it prompts User with pop modal:

> "Do you want to download "19"?

When User selects "x" from the iOS modal to close it, the destroy action completes.

Why is iOS prompting the User to download something? I tried:

```
<%= link_to destroy_nation_notifications_path(notification), method: :delete, download: false do %>
```

Looking for a solution so that iOS will **not** prompt the User to download anything, and instead destroys the Nation Notification without a redirect from the Nation's Index view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I'm not sure why that setup causes iOS to prompt the User to download something. But instead of doing the route setup as above, I just stuck with the simple resources

Routes:

```
resources :nation_notifications
```

The link in ERB:

```
  <%= link_to nation_notification_path(notification), method: :delete do %>
    <span class="dismiss-btn gray float-right">ⓧ</span>
  <% end %>
```

And the Controller:

```
  def destroy
    @nation_issue = NationIssue.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @nation_issue.destroy
    redirect_to nation_issues_path
  end
```